# Postsharp licence error using VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, postsharp

I downloaded version 4.1.13 of PostSharp and got the Express(free) license, and have been trying to use it with VS2013. Whenever I try to build a project that needs PostSharp I get the error "License error. The user license 'MY_LICENSE_NUMBER_HERE' is invalid or has expired." Everything I have found online about this error seems to be from 2013 when the license process was changed and people were trying to use new licenses with old versions of PostSharp. I have even tried deleting the old license and getting a new Express license and continue getting the same error just with a different number in place of 'MY_LICENSE_NUMBER_HERE'. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: PostSharp comes in form of two components: PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio and PostSharp Nuget package. Please, are you sure that both components are in version 4.1.13?